# Yesod - shared types between server and client

Tags: haskell, yesod, elm, ghcjs

I'm used to working with Dart, where sharing types between server and client is as simple as importing the relevant packages into your project.

Can something similar be accomplished with Yesod/Haskell? Should I use GHCJS for the client? Maybe Elm? The goal is not having to worry about the data getting mangled in transit between server and client - and also not having to write a single line of JS.  :o)

I haven't been able to find any good, beginner friendly docs on how to best tackle this challenge using Haskell. I suspect I just haven't looked in the right places. Any and all help is more than welcome.

Comment: There's the [elm-export](https://github.com/krisajenkins/elm-export) project which creates types and decoders based on a Haskell types. That looks like the most recently maintained of the bunch.

Comment: There's also [haste.app](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haste-compiler-0.4/docs/Haste-App.html), a "type-safe client-server communication framework".  I don't know if it would integrate well with Yesod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this with `GHCJS` you can just build your project out of three core packages in this fashion:

- frontend - something based on ghcjs-dom, I like [Reflex-dom](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-dom)
- backend - use your favorite framework, I like [Snap](http://snapframework.com/), Yesod should work just the same
- shared - code shared between frontend and backend

Where frontend and backend both depend on shared of course. Frontend is compiled with `GHCJS`, backend with `GHC`.

If you would like to see a complete example I would highly recommend studying [hsnippet](https://github.com/mightybyte/hsnippet). Take a look at [`WsApi.hs`](https://github.com/mightybyte/hsnippet/blob/6e901fea210a2717ec7800b8d3bcd60740fdc232/shared/src/HSnippet/Shared/WsApi.hs) where a set of up and downstream messages is being defined. All the JSON instances are derived in one place and imported in both frontend and backend.

Hsnippet uses websockets. This is not a requirement of course. You could use regular XHR in your own app. The principle stays the same. You define your API and serialization instances (usually JSON) in the shared package and import the relevant modules in both frontend and backend.

Personally I also share validation code, database entity definitions generated with persistent etc. Once you set it up sharing additional stuff is mostly a copy paste to one of the shared modules and then import wherever.